# EF insert not follow db auto increment(DB First)

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

**.EDMX**

```
<Property Name="uid" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
```

EF had set the StoreGeneratedPattern = "Identity", but why I still cannot save into db? Debug show that the value are always 0, guess is quite correct as server not return the value to the web before inserting, but **model validate always false**, and I had go through 
[C#, entity framework, auto increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188194/c-entity-framework-auto-increment-problem)
and
[Autonumber with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011764/autonumber-with-entity-framework/3038265#3038265)
but no luck, what am I doing wrong? Any idea?

**Update 1:**

Added model and meta data picture, forgot to mention that Im using **EF DB first** to generate the class

**ASP.NET MVC View**

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.uid)
</div>
```

**ASP.NET MVC Controller**

```
[HttpPost, ValidateJsonAntiForgeryToken]
        public JsonResult Create(BasicUserInfo basicuserinfo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.BasicUserInfoes.Add(basicuserinfo);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else 
            {
                return Json(new { valid = "N", err = CaptureError() });
            }

            return Json(new { valid = "Y", route = Url.Action("Index") });
        }
```

**Script**

```
            var self = this;
            var data = "";
            var _model = new model();
            var data = JSON.stringify({ "BasicUserInfo": $(e.currentTarget).serializeObject() });
                var _Create = new Create();
                _Create.fetch({
                    type: 'POST',
                    headers: headers,
                    data: data,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        if (textStatus.valid == "Y") {
                            _model.AppendAddSuccess(textStatus.route);
                        } else {
                            _model.AppendFailed(textStatus.err);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(textStatus.statusText);
                    }
                });
```

**SQL Server 2008**
[image]

**Error**

[image]

**Modal**
[image]

**MetaData**

[image]

Comment: How is your identity column defined on the database?  Is it an Identity?

Comment: yeah, screen capture for SQL server 2008 attached show that the column is identity

Comment: Can we see the entirety of your model? And how you are submitting your view to your controller on creation?

Comment: Updated with the picture of model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Entity Framework is not recognizing the property as a table field. When creating an entity, you also shouldn't need to specify an html helper for its primary key if it is set to IsIdentity = true. If EF recognizes the entity, it will automatically generate a primary key for this field. Therefore you only need html helpers for its other fields.

Make sure your model property is the same name as your database column. In this case, your db column should be titled `uid` it looks like. You can specify the target column in your model using the `Column` attribute if you don't want to change your db tables.

Comment: Yes, it is the same name as DB, Edit and delete work great as the uid is grab from db, but not for create

Comment: For create, try completely removing your html helper for uid. It shouldn't need one.

Comment: awww, thanks for the help, after remove the uid from the Create, it work perfectly, thanks :)