# Get id of new record from mssql using entity in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity

I need to get id of newly created record form mssql. I read some information and still unclear. It says I can just do the following:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
  context.MyEntities.AddObject(myNewObject);
  context.SaveChanges();

  int id = myNewObject.Id; // Yes it's here
}
```

Is it enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Just you saved, you get the new value

be sure that you set the  Identity attribute

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ID { get; set; }
```

Have a look for:
[C#, entity framework, auto increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188194/c-entity-framework-auto-increment-problem)