# How to write this stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

I have a table `Student`. This table has a column `ID` which is auto-increment. I want to write a stored procedure to add a new student and return the `ID`. I'm newbie at this.

This is my code. Please check if it's wrong and fix for me and show me how to code to use it in C#. I used Entity Framework 4.

```
@Name NVARCHAR(50),
@Birthday DATETIME, 
@ID bigint OUTPUT 
AS 
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT ON 

    BEGIN 
       INSERT INTO [Student](Name, Birthday) VALUES (@Name, @Birthday);  
       SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END
END
```

Comment: Do i need to show all my tried here ?

Comment: Yes, you need to show us that you're asking for help, and not asking us to do your work for you.

Comment: I tried to show that but my english is so bad :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better you can `C#` code instead `SP` when your working with `EF4`.

Using Entity Framework, this is all done automagically for you.

```
using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
{
    var student =  new Student()
    {
      Name = "some value",
      Birthday = "some Birthday"
    };

    context.Students.AddObject(student);

    context.SaveChanges();

    int ID = student.ID; // You will get here the Auto-Incremented table ID value.
}
```

Saving in Entity Framework will automatically update the "auto-increment" ID column. You just read it out after the call to .SaveChanges();

EDIT:

Also read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011764/autonumber-with-entity-framework/3038265#3038265) if you encounter any issues getting the "auto-increment" ID value.

Comment: Question: why only small-sized records?

Comment: Sorry it is Typo.. You can use for any :). Edited post accordingly. Thanks John for finding.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Name NVARCHAR(50),
@Birthday DATETIME, 
@ID bigint OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SET XACT_ABORT ON   
BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO [Student](Name,Birthday)
    VALUES(@Name,@Birthday);

    SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

I just added commas in between fields

Answer (score -1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx

This should provide you all the information you need to build a C# application calling your Stored Procedure.

Comment: So true, but it was used to create a SP which can be used correctly with the SQLCommand object. Although, I understand that the answer provided by Prasad Kanaparthi is a better alternative.